# Can I safely assume that Django models IDs are unique upon save()

Tags: django, django-models

I need to store matches in my database and those matches already have a unique ID where they come from. For further assistance and referring, it is best for me to keep this ID:

```
match = Match(id=my8digitsid)
match.save()
```

However, incoming matches (not played yet) don't have an ID yet. Can I safely save my match as follow:

```py
match = Match()
match.save
```

And then, once the match played modify it as such:

```py
match.id = my8digitsid
```

When I say safely, I mean whether or not that the default ID generated (auto-incremented I guess) is unique and won't have any conflicts with my *self-made* IDs.

Comment: Why don't you make another field for your special ID instead?

Comment: This is a recipe for disaster. Use @Leonardo's suggestion and leave the built-in ID alone.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yeah I just hate composed variable names, and too fussy not to use `id` to store an ID :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can be sure that the ORM will make unique id's as referred in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/). The database is the one calculating the new number.

> If a model has an AutoField — an auto-incrementing primary key — then
>   that auto-incremented value will be calculated and saved as an
>   attribute on your object the first time you call save():

```
>>> b2 = Blog(name='Cheddar Talk', tagline='Thoughts on cheese.')
>>> b2.id     # Returns None, because b doesn't have an ID yet.
>>> b2.save()
>>> b2.id     # Returns the ID of your new object. There’s no way to tell what the value of an ID will be before you call save(), because
```

> that value is calculated by your database, not by Django.
>
> For convenience, each model has an AutoField named id by default
>   unless you explicitly specify primary_key=True on a field in your
>   model.

You can also provide the Id if you want using this. I copy below the info from Django documentation.

> Explicitly specifying auto-primary-key values If a model has an
>   AutoField but you want to define a new object’s ID explicitly when
>   saving, just define it explicitly before saving, rather than relying
>   on the auto-assignment of the ID:
>
> ```
> >>> b3 = Blog(id=3, name='Cheddar Talk', tagline='Thoughts on cheese.')
> >>> b3.id     # Returns 3.
> >>> b3.save()
> >>> b3.id     # Returns 3.
> ```
>
> If you assign auto-primary-key values manually, make sure not to use
>   an already-existing primary-key value! If you create a new object with
>   an explicit primary-key value that already exists in the database,
>   Django will assume you’re changing the existing record rather than
>   creating a new one.
>
> Given the above 'Cheddar Talk' blog example, this example would
>   override the previous record in the database:

```
b4 = Blog(id=3, name='Not Cheddar', tagline='Anything but cheese.')
b4.save()  # Overrides the previous blog with ID=3!
```

But I don't recommend You to assign that ID yourself. I think more convenient to create a field of the model with the ID from where they come from.

The reason Why I don't recommend this is because you will have to verify always that the id provided has not been used before before inserting it. As a general rule I try to avoid modifying the standard behaviour of Django as much as possible.

Comment: May I ask why ? I mean, for what case did they keep this *feature* enabled.

Comment: I hope my answer helps you out with this.

Comment: Yes it does :] However you point out that I should check whether or not that my custom ID is unique but being the default primary key of any model, it has something like `unique=True` right (and thus raises some exception by itself) ?

Comment: It doesn't rise an exception if the item already exist, as stated above, it modifies the old item if it exists. I copy here the details of the documentation `For convenience, each model has an AutoField named id by default unless you explicitly specify primary_key=True on a field in your model. See the documentation for AutoField for more details.
' also check this page. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField and this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields for more info.